# Apache dispatch.fcgi doesn't get interpreted with Passenger

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I've installed passenger as ruby gem. I've added following to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4
```

and set Vitual Host to rails app ~/public directory, but when I visit the site, I only see content of **dispatch.fcgi**, but nothing gets executed

.htaccess in ~/public directory is

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

However, if I run script/server, everything works fine, so there is no problem with the application itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passenger doesn't execute Rails requests via dispatch.fcgi.  Have you tried following the Passenger installation instructions?

Comment: yep, I even ran through http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html two timeson different machines, once with gem and once with ubuntu package, but neither did help

Comment: Nothing in that documentation mentions dispatch.fcgi.

Comment: dispatch is generated when you do rails xx -D, thats because I migrated project from other other server, where it was necessary, anyway, problem solved by rebooting whole server (apache reboot didn't suffice)

Comment: Rails generates a lot of things, but that doesn't mean you have to use them.