# Rebooting whole server for Rails

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I'm migrating a Rails project onto an Apache server. I've followed the steps similarly to [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/60222/apache-dispatch-fcgi-doesnt-get-interpreted-with-passenger) (installed passenger as ruby gem, added some lines to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, set Vitual Host to rails app ~/public directory.)

When I visit the site, I only see content of dispatch.fcgi. That link mentions that the problem is solved by rebooting whole server (apache reboot didn't suffice). I'm not familiar with servers, and I'm not sure what rebooting the whole server means, or how I can do it.

Comment: You can reboot the whole server from the terminal by issuing `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying to reboot the complete server, try to restart Apache first.

Depending on your distribution, one of this commands should work:

`service httpd restart`

`service apache2 restart`

`/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Depending on the distribution and your user rights, you might need to prepend `sudo` in front of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

To reboot, I have always used the following sequence:

```
cd //
sync
init 6
```